# PHP - скриптом скачать файл по FTP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Не получается скриптом скачать файлы с "чужого" (не хостинга) ftp-сервера.

Пробовал через

1)CURL

2)file_put_content+file_get_content

3)copy

4)ftp_get

Почему-то получается скачать файлы с ftp-хостинга, но не удается скачать со сторонних ftp (скрипт отрабатывает около минуты, без ошибок, и создает пустой файл).

Может это какие-то ограничения/особенности на хостинге?

Comment: а зачем вы залезли в "чужой сервер" ? что то крадём?

Comment: - производитель выкладывает свою выгрузку (для клиентов) на ftp.. а не через привычный http

Comment: а скрипт запускается с под апача/нджинкса?

Comment: скрипт запускается через хостинг (по URL). Свой локальный ftp-хостинга работает всеми способами, ftp-нужного сервера - ни одним. Может какие-то переменные есть, где можно убедиться что какая-то настройка для службы работает в ограниченном режиме?

Comment: С другого хостинга всё работает, с нужного - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Для такой задачи вам надо использовать функцию `ftp_get`

```
<?php

$LocalfileName = 'file.php';
$ServerfileName = 'file.php';
$ftp_server="server.ru";
$ftp_username="ftp логин";
$ftp_userpass="ftp пароль";

$conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);


if (ftp_get($conn, $LocalfileName, $ServerfileName, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Файл  $LocalfileName \n";
}
else {
    echo "Ошибка\n";
}

ftp_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но тоже уже пробовал (результат аналогичный). Хотя вот с 3-м параметром её "не играл", может как-то с этим связано

Comment: читаем документацию ))  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: Еще на несколько раз перекрутил ftp_get - не помогло. Валится на коннекте. Либо дело в каких-то ограничениях сервера хостинга, либо в ограничениях со стороны сервера-владельца ftp.

Comment: Попробовали с другого хостинга - всё работает (догадка оправдалась). Остается вопрос - что на старом хостинге не так?

Comment: На хостинге отключена возможность работы ftp_connect и т.д, пишите сапорту, они активируют.